# How to install Hawtio in JBoss Fuse 6.0

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, hawtio

I have JBoss Fuse 6.0.0. It seems there is no Hawtio component in here. How to install it in JBoss Fuse 6.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to install it by executing:

```
features:addurl mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.27/xml/features
features:install hawtio-core`
```

in your karaf console. Further details can be found on the [hawtio website](http://hawt.io/getstarted/) (section: Using Apache Karaf or Apache ServiceMix)

Answer (score 1):

In JBoss Fuse 6.0.0 it is called "fabric-webui"

```
`features:install fabric-webui`
```

Note: that version is very dated. Strongly recommend upgraded